# Invalide Date when creating new Date?

Tags: javascript

I want to find out if the current UTC time is at least xx hours (for example 12, 24, 48 or 72 hours) bigger than the given UTC time. The given UTC time always consists of UTCyear, UTCmonth, UTCdate, UTChour and UTCminute.

I have tried it with this code, but it's not always working. For example, the code is not working in this case:

```js
  function isOlderThan12Hours(dateToCheck)
  {
      return Date.now() - dateToCheck > 43200;  // 12 hours = 43200 seconds
  }

  var year = 2020;
  var month = 3;  // April
  var date = 17;
  var hour = 11;
  var minute = 39;

  const valuesAsDate = new Date(`${year}-${month+1}-${date}T${hour}:${minute}:00.000Z`);
  console.log(`${year}-${month+1}-${date}T${hour}:${minute}:00.000Z`, valuesAsDate);
```

In this case, valuesAsDate = Invalid Date.
What is wrong with this code?

How can I find out if the current UTC time is at xx hours bigger than the given UTC time?

Comment: Your valuesAsDate is invalid Date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem with how you add month in your date. If month is smaller than 9 then add a 0 has to be added as prefix to make it a 2 digit number.

```js
var year = 2020;
var month = 3;  // April
var pref="";
var date = 17;
var hour = 11;
var minute = 39;

if(month<9){pref="0"}
const valuesAsDate = new Date(`${year}-${pref}${month+1}-${date}T${hour}:${minute}:00.000Z`);
console.log(valuesAsDate);
```

Comment: It should be `<= 9`

Comment: Oh nvm sorry, I got blind